# Shrink extended partition containing lvm

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm

I have been bashing my head against the wall, regretting ever having opted into using LVM.

[image: Gparted screenshot]]

I need to shrink the 75GB /dev/sda2/ to make room for a new OS installation. To do this, I need to shrink the /dev/sd5 partition which is contained in sd2.

I first attempted to use GParted, but my version says it does not support LVM. I downloaded the latest .iso for GParted Live into a CD, but the results were similar.

So I have already taken all the steps to shrink the filesystem, volume group, physical volume, and so on.

```
user@computer:~$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree   
  /dev/sda5  ubuntu lvm2 a-   56.00g 1020.00m



user@computer:~$ sudo lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/ubuntu/root
  VG Name                ubuntu
  LV UUID                blahblahblah
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                55.00 GiB
  Current LE             14080
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
```

I have even removed the swap_1 volume. 
When I run the latest GParted from the LiveCD, it does show the used 56GB volume group, then some 18GB unallocated space. However, it still does not let me resize /dev/sda5 or /dev/sda2. How can I resize /dev/sda2, given that the volume group and physical volumes are already 55GB, while is 18GB less than the size of the containing extended partition /dev/sd2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by accidentally deleting the `/dev/sd2` extended partition (via 'parted'--I thought, like fdisk, parted would not commit the changes immediately).

I then used testdisk to look for lost partitions. It found /dev/sd5, and considered it a primary partition. (It did not find the extended partition `/dev/sd2`).

After this, I was able to use gparted to resize and do operations onto the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the smartest solution:

use the tool system-config-lvm to migrate your data to another (temporal, external hard drive) device, delete the partition / do your resizing and migrate the data back.

hope that helps

Comment: I fixed this by accidentally deleting the /dev/sd2 extended partition (via 'parted