# How to shrink LVM2-designated partition without recreating it?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I've installed Ubuntu with LVM2 and now I want to make a new partition on that disk. I've shrank the root virtual volume and now swap volume is located on last extents of the physical volume. AFAIU that prevents physical volume resizing. But I can't find any info on how to move that swap closer to root and shrink the physical volume.
I've already found two identical questions but they were resolved in ways unacceptable in my case:

In this one user just deleted the partition: [Shrink extended partition containing lvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281920/shrink-extended-partition-containing-lvm)

And in this one user just gave up: [Move free space out of LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165731/move-free-space-out-of-lvm)

Comment: This is a problem with LVM, it is easy to increase the size, but not reduce the size. There is no sulution other then what you found , back up your data and start again.

Comment: @Panther can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as solved? Doesn't look like I'll find a way anyway.